# Upgrade from ojdbc7 to ojdbc8 for java application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jar

I’m using eclipse and I’m trying to upgrade my java application from ojdbc7 to 8. I’m not sure how to approch this the only clue I got was replacing the file at WebContent/WEB-INF/lib

Do I continue what I’m doing then recompile the whole java application to make it work with the new ojdbc8?

Or what should I exactly do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver you use does not impact the compilation of your own code, but you should rebuild the application and redeploy the WAR file because the updated JAR needs to be distributed with your app.

The JDBC Driver Manager will do the class loading like magic without you changing a line of code, by the way that was one of the things that made people UOU in 2000 because everyone was used to methods like mysql_connect (from php)

First replace the JAR file, then rebuild and export, and if you want to make sure the jar is there, just open the WAR file with winzip and check it. The WAR file is a JAR file in reality and you can open it with Winzip or Winrar

Comment: So I should first replace the jar file at WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
 then rebuild the project after that deploy the war file?

Comment: exactly, first replace, then rebuild, and if you want to make sure the jar is there, just open the war file with winzip and check it. The war file is a JAR file in reality and you can open it with Winzip or Winrar